# Migrating and rolling back DynamoDB data in conjunction with SAM Deploy

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, migration, database-migration

I'm considering the best way of migrating and subsequently rolling back if necessary data in a DynamoDB table automatically, in conjunction with a release.

In past systems I've used and written there has been a way to do this - usually something like upgrade lump of sql to go up, and a downgrade lump to go down...so, something like, in pseudo terms:

```
1.1.0:
UPGRADE="""
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = "y", modified = "whoReallyCaresIfThisWorks,YouGetTheIdea";
WHERE column1 = "x"  
"""

DOWNGRADE="""
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = "x", modified = ''
WHERE column1 = "y" AND modified = "whoReallyCaresIfThisWorks,YouGetTheIdea"; 
"""
```

Upgrade to 1.1.0 from the previous version sets x to y, downgrade back sets y to x

But, I don't see any obvious prior art about how to do this in the world of SAM templates and DynamoDB.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that even that dummy statement is not correct in its result because the downgrade might affect columns that were `y` even before the upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, okay. But, it's not actually real, you'll note. You get the idea - is there a proper way do data migrations with DynamoDB and SAM deployments. Edited to that end.